# Java - Edit instance variables without a method

Tags: java, variables, object, instance

I am quite new to Java, and I am constantly looking for ways to improve my code. But I don't seem to get this, if it is even possible to do.

Let's say I have this code (I edited out the irrelevant parts, so the code might seem weird):

```
public class NewBody {

public static int distanceScale = 5;

    public int x, y;
    public float xMeter = x * distanceScale;
    public float yMeter = y * distanceScale;

    public NewBody(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void pixToMeter(){
         this.xMeter = distanceScale * this.x;
    }
```

If I don't call pixToMeter() and just try to use "instance.xMeter" directly, it just returns the vaulue 0, even though I've already set the x variable in the constructor.

So my question is: Is there a way to properly set variables without calling a method to do it? It seems highly unneccessary since I am not even passing a parameter to it.

Sorry for my poor english, I hope you understand what I am trying to say.

Answer (score 4):

The initialisation of xMeter is done when x is still zero.

This is what actually happens:

```
public NewBody(int x, int y) {
    // All fields are zeroed: 0, null, 0.0.

    super(); // Object constructor, as Object is the parent class.

    // Those fields that are initialized:
    xMeter = this.x * distanceScale; // 0.0f * 5
    yMeter = this.y * distanceScale;

    // The rest of the constructor:
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

For a depending value:

```
public final void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
    xMeter = this.x * distanceScale;
}
```

And to apply the DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself): one could drop the initialisation of xMeter and call setX(x) in the constructor instead.

When called in the constructor it is important to make `setX` final, that is: not overridable.

Comment: @Makoto You mean the `Yhe`? :P

Comment: That's what I get for eating an ice cream sandwich and copy-editing.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. However, I have one question if you do not mind. What happens if I want to change the x value with a simple method like: instance.setX(int x){ this.x = x}? The xMeter variable does not seem to update, it still prints out the value it was initialized with

Comment: @Makoto Now you made me jealous ... are you happy now? :D

Comment: @supsupsupsup There is no way in Java to say "update a variable automatically when some other variable is changed".  If you want to change a variable, you have to execute an assignment statement that changes it.  Period.

Comment: @supsupsupsup: I added `setX` to deal with changing xMeter on changing x.

Comment: Oh okay, good to know :) Damn, that fix looks good. Why didn't I think of that

Answer (score 2):

The source of the problem is here:

```
public float xMeter = x * distanceScale;
```

The issue is that you're initializing this instance variable **outside** the constructor. As a result, since `x` is initialized to 0, the result of your multiplication is also 0.

If you need `xMeter` and `yMeter` initialized to a value based on `x` or `y`, simply declare them as you did the other fields:

```
public int xMeter;
```

And initialize their values in the constructor:

```
public newBody(int x, int y){
    // initialize x and y ...
    this.xMeter = x * distanceScale;
```

Comment: Late to the party I see. Typing on my phone.

Comment: You at least give a solution.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. However, I have one question if you do not mind.

What happens if I want to change the x value with a simple method like: instance.setX(int x){ this.x = x}? The xMeter variable does not seem to update, it still prints out the value it was initialized with

Comment: @supsupsupsup also update the `xMeter` variable inside the `setX` method (after you have set `this.x`). But you should consider using a getter method instead of using direct access to the variable (buzzword: *encapsulation *).

Comment: @supsupsupsup What Tom said is correct. You will need to update the meter variables in the setter method (or call another general "update" method to do that). Or, another possible approach is to ditch those meter variables altogether, and simply make a getter method that returns `x * distanceScale`; from what we can see, unless there's something else preventing you from doing so, you might not need to store a variable that's calculated and recalculated like that every time.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, when the `xMeter` is initialized, the constructor is not called yet and `x` is still `0`, so the value of `xMeter` is `0` as well.

To change that, you must update `xMeter`'s value once `x` is initialized in the constructor, like so:

```
public NewBody(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    // update x and y meter
    xMeter = x * distanceScale;
    yMeter = y * distanceScale;
}
```

However, you mentioned how you want `xMeter` to update every time `x` is changed as well. As it stands with your current code, that will not happen. However, a suggestion of mine would be to create a *method* to change the value of `x` (and `y` as well) and in those methods, also update the values of `xMeter` and `yMeter`. That way, whenever you want to change `x`, call the methods and it will update your other values too.

Try adding these methods and changing your constructor to this:

```
// called setter methods
public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
    this.xMeter = x * distanceScale;
}
public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
    this.yMeter = y * distanceScale;
}

// constructor
public NewBody(int x, int y){
    setX(x);
    setY(y);
}
```

Comment: Thaank you! Really genius, wish I would have though of that